# Include TestNG to hybrid selenium framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have the below code in driverscript. I need to embed TestNG to it. How can I do this? ActionKeywords.java is defining all the action keywords.
Where should I give the TestNG annotation?
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.lang.reflect.Method;
    import java.util.Properties;

```
import org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator;

import config.ActionKeywords;
import config.Constants;
import utility.ExcelUtils;
import utility.Log;

public class DriverScript {

    public static Properties OR;
    public static ActionKeywords actionKeywords;
    public static String sActionKeyword;
    public static String sPageObject;
    public static Method method[];


    public static int iTestStep;
    public static int iTestLastStep;
    public static String sTestCaseID;
    public static String sRunMode;
    public static String sData;
    public static boolean bResult;

    public DriverScript() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException{
        actionKeywords = new ActionKeywords();
        method = actionKeywords.getClass().getMethods();    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Constants.Path_TestData);
        DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml");
        String Path_OR = Constants.Path_OR;
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(Path_OR);
        OR= new Properties(System.getProperties());
        OR.load(fs);        
        DriverScript startEngine = new DriverScript();
        startEngine.execute_TestCase();

    }

    private void execute_TestCase() throws Exception {
            int iTotalTestCases = ExcelUtils.getRowCount(Constants.Sheet_TestCases);
            System.out.println("Total TC count" + iTotalTestCases);  
            for(int iTestcase=1;iTestcase<iTotalTestCases;iTestcase++){
                bResult = true;
                sTestCaseID = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestcase, Constants.Col_TestCaseID, Constants.Sheet_TestCases); 
                sRunMode = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestcase, Constants.Col_RunMode,Constants.Sheet_TestCases);
                if (sRunMode.equals("Yes")){
                    Log.startTestCase(sTestCaseID);
                    iTestStep = ExcelUtils.getRowContains(sTestCaseID, Constants.Col_TestCaseID, Constants.Sheet_TestSteps);
                    iTestLastStep = ExcelUtils.getTestStepsCount(Constants.Sheet_TestSteps, sTestCaseID, iTestStep);
                    bResult=true;
                    for (;iTestStep<iTestLastStep;iTestStep++){
                        sActionKeyword = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestStep, Constants.Col_ActionKeyword,Constants.Sheet_TestSteps);
                        sPageObject = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestStep, Constants.Col_PageObject, Constants.Sheet_TestSteps);
                        sData = ExcelUtils.getCellData(iTestStep, Constants.Col_DataSet, Constants.Sheet_TestSteps);
                        execute_Actions();
                        if(bResult==false){
                            ExcelUtils.setCellData(Constants.KEYWORD_FAIL,iTestcase,Constants.Col_Result,Constants.Sheet_TestCases);
                            Log.endTestCase(sTestCaseID);
                            break;
                            }                       
                        }
                    if(bResult==true){
                    ExcelUtils.setCellData(Constants.KEYWORD_PASS,iTestcase,Constants.Col_Result,Constants.Sheet_TestCases);
                    Log.endTestCase(sTestCaseID);   
                        }                   
                    }
                }
            }   

     private static void execute_Actions() throws Exception {

        for(int i=0;i<method.length;i++){
            if(method[i].getName().equals(sActionKeyword)){
                method[i].invoke(actionKeywords,sPageObject, sData);
                if(bResult==true){              
                    ExcelUtils.setCellData(Constants.KEYWORD_PASS, iTestStep, Constants.Col_TestStepResult, Constants.Sheet_TestSteps);
                    break;
                }else{
                    ExcelUtils.setCellData(Constants.KEYWORD_FAIL, iTestStep, Constants.Col_TestStepResult, Constants.Sheet_TestSteps);
                    ActionKeywords.closeBrowser("","");
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
     }

}
```

Comment: You can find very good and easy steps here : http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/install-testng/

Comment: Hi I have installed. What are the code changes required?

Comment: Code changes you can do as per annotations , groups that is depends on you..Also create XML to run program more smoothly.

Comment: So you mean we need @Test notation for each test case?
For adding one test case we need to make any modification to the code?

Comment: No code modification require. Just add necessary annotation before your code and run it.

Comment: But if I do so all the test case will be executed as single test case.For example , if I add @Test annotation before 'execute_TestCase', that method will be considered as a single test case. But in actual there will be multiple test case in excel which that method parses

Comment: Then you can depart your code based on annotation if you want to give priority to execute tests.

Comment: So from my understanding, it is not a practice to use TestNG along with keyword framework since the advantage of code independence from Test case will be hampered. Am I right?

Comment: No , you can use TestNG. You can specify in priority for ex: 1 - Read data from excel , 2 - write data to excel , 3 - any other execution.. So you can specify what you want to execute first and then other sequence.

Comment: How the above code can be modified?

Comment: for that please check sample program here : http://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-data-provider-excel/

Comment: Thanks for the help.. Seems like this link will do for me :)